# Error Connecting Vidyo from Android

Tags: android, vidyo

I have a problem connecting an app with Vidyo in Android. The code that i'm using is the same that the demo https://github.com/Vidyo/helloworld-vidyo.io-android. The error is:

```
03-10 19:40:55.319 20075-20075/com.example.pfuternik.vidyoiodemo I/vidyo-sdk: 2018-03-11 00:40:55.319 +00:00|ERROR   |LmiTransport   |[System thread]|Error resolving address prod.vidyo.io:443: NoAddresses
03-10 19:40:55.333 20075-20075/com.example.pfuternik.vidyoiodemo I/vidyo-sdk: 2018-03-11 00:40:55.333 +00:00|WARNING |VidyoClient    |[System thread]|VidyoUserLogin Could not perform latency test for https://prod.vidyo.io:443/static/poolreflectors.json
03-10 19:40:55.334 20075-20075/com.example.pfuternik.vidyoiodemo I/vidyo-sdk: 2018-03-11 00:40:55.334 +00:00|ERROR   |LmiTransport   |[System thread]|Error resolving address prod.vidyo.io:443: NoAddresses
03-10 19:40:55.334 20075-20075/com.example.pfuternik.vidyoiodemo I/vidyo-sdk: 2018-03-11 00:40:55.334 +00:00|ERROR   |LmiSignaling   |[System thread]|Could not create connection to a5cb3d1be33655bb
03-10 19:40:55.366 20075-20246/com.example.pfuternik.vidyoiodemo I/vidyo-sdk: 2018-03-11 00:40:55.366 +00:00|ERROR   |VidyoConnector |Execute Async-0|VidyoConnectorConnectFailed VIDYO_CONNECTORFAILREASON_ConnectionFailed
```

I tried to generate the token with three diferents methods:

1. Using the jar file
2. Using this page: https://vidyocreatetoken.appspot.com
3. Taking it from the meetings room like the tutorial https://support.vidyo.io/hc/en-us/articles/115001214094-Build-a-Simple-Video-Chat-App-on-Android

I'm using two devices and i'm getting the same result, what's wrong?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: Hello, no I didn't  :( I changed to tokbox.com

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same error and it is working if I connect my device to the internet